# Please help me to understand Context

Tags: android, android-context

I have hard a big time trying to understand how Context stuff really works. I don't really need this now, but I am sure I will need this soon...

**EXAMPLE**

I made an app called `ave` and a library (itself an app) called `xvf` with several activities each. Most of them give info through a Toast, so I have everywhere the same method:

```
public void info(String txt) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Now I thought to put that method as a class in the library, and call it from everywhere, both from the app classes and the library classes. I do **not** want to pass the context, like `info.show(context, String)`, I want the class `info` to infer where the context is when it is being called.

So I made a class called `info`:

```
package com.floritfoto.apps.xvf;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class info extends Activity{
    private Context context;

    public info() {
        super();
        context = (Context)getApplicationContext();
    }
    public void show(String txt) {
        Toast.makeText(context, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Then, on the calling activity, I just create an instance of info, and do `info.show(String)`. This works.

Problem is that it seems too expensive for mee to `extend Activity` just to get the context...

Which is the correct way of doing what I want? It would be even better to do a `info(String)` thing... Remember, you are not allowed to make a constructor `info(Context, String)`, that's cheating.

Comment: Passing the context as a variable is the right way to do it. Why is this an issue?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in passing the context when it clearly is bound to it.

Comment: @Eric, @iccthedral: There is nothing 'wrong' in passing the context. I just want to _understand_ how Context works, and how the `info` class can get the Context of the loader class. So passing the context is cheating... :o)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's working by sheer blind luck.

You can't instantiate a *proper* Activity with `new`, you have to let the Android framework do that. In this case it's working because you're getting the *Application* context, which I guess it figures out by package owner.

In reality, an `Activity` is itself a `Context` (it extends it) so you could use `this` when showing a Toast. If you tried to do that in your `info` class I imagine it would fail. Anyway, like Eric pointed out, if you need a `Context` in a library class (that's not a proper Activity), you need to pass it in as a parameter to use it.

Comment: I didn't instantiate the class with new. I used its method `info.show`.

Comment: `info.show()` isn't static, so you *have* to be calling `new` at some point or other...

Comment: Plus you said "Then, on the calling activity, I just create an instance of info"

Comment: Sorry, sorry, you're right. With the code above, I created an instance of `info`. But afterwards I changed the code by `public static void show(...` to be able just to call `info.show`, only needing an import, with no instance.